# Is there a way to check the status of a renewable subscription from WatchOS?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, storekit, auto-renewable

I have a WatchOS app that offers several watch-specific features. Some of them are locked behind a subscription paywall.

I need a way to check about once a month whether or not the user is still subscribed to the app.

I could simply prompt the user to open the iOS app once a month to inform the Watch app of the subscription status, but that isn't very user friendly.

Since StoreKit is not available on WatchOS, I'm not sure what to do.

Is there a way to reliably wake up the iOS app in the background once a month to check the subscription status and send the results back to the Watch?

Comment: I think, the best you can do is to add background-refresh capability to your iOS app - as and when iOS will wakes your iOS app you will have some 30 seconds time to check for the subscription and also send the data back to your watch-app (if requires). That way, you will make sure for the status. If no status available, then what you're doing right now is looks fine with the dev limitations. Hope this will help.